# Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API - Identify vs. FindSimilar

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api, facial-identification

I am building a celebrity matching facial recognition service. I have multiple pictures for each celebrity, and I want to match the user's query face to the closest celebrity. There are two ways to do this using Microsoft's Cognitive Services Face API:

- **[FaceList - FindSimilar](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239)** to find the closest single face
- **[PersonGroup - Identify](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395237)** to find the closest person (making use of all faces)

Both can be used with 0 threshold (include all results), but which one would be more accurate? I am concerned whether multiple pictures in different light conditions, with different hairstyle, etc. used together will help or trip the detection accuracy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do, if you want to return a collection of similar faces to the user based on their query, then go for **Face - Find Similar**, but if you just want to identify the people in a photo and return the possible identified person then **Face - Identify** would be the right choice.

Using multiple pictures in different light conditions, different hairstyles, and etc. for training will only increase the accuracy.